# Statistical test for multiple conditions and features with replicates

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have data from a biological experiment of the following form:

```
                           site1   site2   site3   site4
Condition A | replicate1 |  0.30 |  0.15 |  0.50 |  0.05
Condition A | replicate2 |  0.27 |  0.18 |  0.48 |  0.07
Condition B | replicate1 |  0.50 |  0.15 |  0.30 |  0.05
Condition B | replicate2 |  0.47 |  0.18 |  0.38 |  0.07
```

We have two conditions A and B, and two replicates for each condition, giving in total 4 samples. For each of these four samples we measure the usage (how many sequencing reads) at four sites. 
What I want to know is if the usage of these four sites is significantly changes between condition A and B. Any ideas for a clever way how to do this?
Basically, the variation within a condition should be significantly lower than the variation between the two conditions.

Yes, I just used the fraction of sequencing reads up there. The reason is that these are four separate experiments and cannot simply use the raw counts without any normalization. If I just look at the relative usage of each site in each experiment I can avoid the normalization step. I can scale those numbers to 100 and then I have integers if this helps.

Is this an example of a classical ANOVA? I tried it in R, but isn't the sample size too low to get something meaningful?

```
   condition site1 site2 site3 site4
1         A    30    15    50     5
2         A    27    18    48     7
3         B    50    15    30     5
4         B    47    18    38     7

summary(aov(site1+site2+site3+site4~condition, data=data))
```

Comment: You say that you are measuring "how many sequence reads", but give non-integer numbers. It looks like the row sums are 1, but it would be better if you had the actual counts if possible.

Comment: @grubera7 I've merged your two accounts. However, you'll need to register this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is unclear, and the OP is long gone.